# Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service"

Tags: nginx

Hi so I am currently trying to host my website from home and doing this through oracle free tier I am getting a 403 error and the following error message Job for nginx.service failed. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" I went in to the config file and I don't see anything wrong. But here is the image below[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aarLo.png).
Can someone lease give me a solution it would be very much appreciated.